# How to stay logged into a website using a Python script (requests library)?

Tags: python, http, web, urllib2, python-requests

I am attempting to use the Python [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library to login to a website called surfline.com, then `get` a webpage once logged in (presumably within a persisting [session](http://docs.python-requests.org:8000/en/latest/user/advanced/)).

The login form that surfline.com uses throughout its pages uses `onclick()` to map to a JS function called `verifyLogin()`, which in turn posts to a `.cfm` file. On `success`, it refreshes the page, and the user is now kept logged in so long as the cookies persist.

I am using the [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library for the first time, and am unsure how to:

1. login successfully,
2. stay logged-in throughout the session,
3. then print out the homepage as a logged-in user to the terminal.

Here is the login form (HTML):

```
<form id="loginForm">
    <label for="name">Email Address:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <label for="mail">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <input type="hidden" name="top_login" id="top_login" value="true">
    <button class="surfline-button blue1" type="button" onclick="verifyLogin();">Log In</button>
    <button class="surfline-button grey1" type="button" onclick="jQuery('#dialog-login').dialog('close');">Cancel</button>
    <div id="forgot">Forgot Password? <a href="/myaccount/?action=forgot_password">Click Here</a></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div><input style="float:left; width:18px; height:18px; margin-right:6px; border:none" type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" value="true" checked="checked"><div id="remember-me-text" style="float:left; width:200px; text-align:left; margin-top:1px;">Remember me on this computer?</div></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <p>Not a Premium member?  <a href="https://www.surfline.com/subscribe_vindicia/index.cfm?mkt=login&amp;slintcid=LOGIN&amp;slcmpname=LOGIN-MODAL">TRY PREMIUM FREE NOW</a></p>
</form>
```

Here is the `verifyLogin()` function in the [/05222013_slmenu.js](http://www.surfline.com/global_includes/scripts/05222013_slmenu.js) file:

```
function verifyLogin(){  
    //var username = jQuery("#username").val();
    //var password = jQuery("#password").val();
    var usernameVal = jQuery("#username").val();
    var passwordVal = jQuery("#password").val();
    var rememberMeVal = jQuery("#rememberMe").val();    
    var top_loginVal = jQuery("#top_login").val(); 

    if(usernameVal.length === 0 || passwordVal.length === 0 ){
        jQuery("#login-note").addClass("warning");
        if(usernameVal.length === 0){ jQuery("#username").addClass('warning'); jQuery("#login-note").html("Email Field is Blank"); }else{ jQuery("#username").removeClass('warning');}
        if(passwordVal.length === 0){ jQuery("#password").addClass('warning'); jQuery("#login-note").html("Password Field is Blank"); }else{ jQuery("#password").removeClass('warning'); }
        if(usernameVal.length === 0 && passwordVal.length === 0){jQuery("#login-note").html("Email and Password Fields are Blank"); }
    }else{  
        jQuery("#inner-dialog").fadeOut("slow",function(){
            var htmlData = "<center><div style='padding-top:60px;'><h1>Verifying Login</h1><img src='/global_includes/images/ajax-loader-snake-295284.gif' style='margin-top:24px;'></div></center>";                                                
            jQuery("#verifying").html(htmlData).fadeIn("slow", function(){ 
                //var loginData = jQuery('#loginForm').serialize();

                var loginData = 'username=' + escape(usernameVal) + '&password=' + escape(passwordVal) + '&rememberMe=' + rememberMeVal + '&top_login=' + top_loginVal;

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type:'POST', 
                    url: '/myaccount/inc_login_handler.cfm', 
                    data:loginData, 
                    cache:false,
                    success: function(response){
                        var responseTrimmed = response.replace(/^\s+||\s+$/g,'');
                        if(responseTrimmed != true){    
                             jQuery("#verifying").fadeOut("slow",function(){ jQuery("#inner-dialog").fadeIn("slow"); jQuery("#login-note").html("Unable to find your login information. Please Try Again...").addClass("warning");  jQuery("#username").addClass('warning');  jQuery("#password").addClass('warning'); });
                        }else{ 
                            var successData = "<center><div style='padding-top:60px;'><h1>Success!</h1><img src='/global_includes/images/checkmark.png' style='margin-top:24px; margin-bottom:20px;'><br /> Please Wait, Site Reloading...</div></center>";
                            jQuery("#verifying").fadeOut("slow",function(){  jQuery('#verifying').html(successData).fadeIn("slow"); });
                            setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, 1200 ); 
                        }
                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        jQuery("#verifying").fadeOut("slow",function(){ jQuery("#inner-dialog").fadeIn("slow"); jQuery("#login-note").html("There was an error finding your login infomation. Please Try Again...").addClass("warning");  });
                    }  
                });
            });
        })
    }
}
```

I've tried this code, but can't seem to get the homepage as a logged-in user; it still returns as it would to someone who isn't logged in (my full name should appear in the header, etc.):

```
>>> import requests, json
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> page_signed_out = s.get('http://www.surfline.com/home/index.cfm')
>>> form_data = {'type':'POST',
...              'url':'/myaccount/inc_login_handler.cfm',               
...              'data':"username=myemail@example.com&password=mypassword&rememberMe=true&top_login=true",
...              'cache':False}
>>> s.post(url,
...        data=json.dumps(form_data),
...        headers= {'content-type': 'application/json'})
<Response [200]>
>>> page_signed_in = s.get('http://www.surfline.com/home/index.cfm')
```

Basically, how can I log into surfline.com from a python file, and get a page as a logged in user? I don't mind using a different library, if it is not possible with the `requests` library. Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Here are the cookies after a POST has been made, as suggested by @André

<[Cookie(version=0, name='CRYPTOPASS', value='%296%25%2A%2521B%3FO%2A%3C%28', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.surfline.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=2338694583, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False), Cookie(version=0, name='CRYPTOUSER', value='23%252600%2E3Z%5FM%5EEZV1IK%27TFIW%3E', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.surfline.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=2338694583, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False), Cookie(version=0, name='LOGGED_OUT', value='true', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.surfline.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=2338694583, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False), Cookie(version=0, name='USER_ID', value='259829', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.surfline.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=2338694583, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False), Cookie(version=0, name='CFID', value='437349255', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='www.surfline.com', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=2338694583, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False), Cookie(version=0, name='CFTOKEN', value='1082d1233da237c-3E4C2D43-FFC6-4ECC-1E80D9B505E495CE', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='www.surfline.com', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=2338694583, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried logging in to that website while monitoring the requests made using Firebug, and it looks like data is in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format rather than `application/json`, and also you misinterpreted some values from the Javascript code, the `type`, `url`, `data` and `cache` were parameters for the AJAX call, not the actual data that should be sent to the server.

This is the *hopefully working* code, replace your email and password in the POST request.

```
from requests import Session # we can just import Session, no need to import the entire requests

s = Session() # new session

page_signed_out = s.get('http://www.surfline.com/home/index.cfm') # gets signed out page, this will set eventual cookies that may be needed later

s.post("http://www.surfline.com/myaccount/inc_login_handler.cfm", {"username":"myemail@example.com", "password":"mypassword", "rememberMe":"true", "top_login":"true"}) # does the actual login, if successful this will set a session cookie

page_signed_in = s.get('http://www.surfline.com/home/index.cfm') # good, we're logged in
```

---

**EDIT:**

Or, if for whatever reason, *surfline.com* does not successfully log you in, you can essentially copy the cookies planted in your browser when you physically logged in, and "paste" them into your program, then pass them in with your request.

```
from requests import Session

s = Session()
s.cookies["s_cc"] = "your_session_cookie" # replace this with your actual login cookie

page_signed_in = s.get("http://www.surfline.com") # you're logged in :)
```

Comment: Well, the cookies seem to be present after I post correct data on the `s.post()` call, so it's logging in successfully. However, the second call to 'http://www.surfline.com/home/index.cfm' is still returning the page as if the user was not logged in. Do I have to pass the cookies in as a parameter to the second call, or something similar? (I'll post the `RequestsCookieJar` in the next comment so you can see)

Comment: Actually, it's too long, I'll post as an EDIT in the question

Comment: Checking in Chrome settings, I'm seeing that the cookies that are placed by Surfline upon a successful login are different from the cookies found in the `Session` object (for example, there are some called `USER_ID` and `SETTINGSID`), and there is no `LOGGED_OUT` cookie, as there is in the `Session` object. So, I don't believe the login is happening successfully after all. Is there any way to just run that JavaScript function verbatim from my machine, with the username and password fields written into the file?

Comment: @sgarza62 if the login cookie's lifetime is long enough you can probably just copy paste its value from your browser directly into the script and that's it.

Comment: The copy-paste method was what finally worked. I've edited your post to include it, please accept edit and I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: @sgarza62 I improved your edit, there's no need to use a cookie jar, you can just use `Session`'s "cookies" attribute as a dictionary, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are also a surfer and are just trying to get the streams to play all day I will hint at checking out the RTMP connections their flash player makes..

Even bigger hint:

tcpdump -A -n -s 0 -r file.tcpdump | grep connect

when visiting a cam page and grep for the RTMP stream..

But you might be going for something else and then this would be off topic..

Comment: I was building myself a different frontend representation of the forecast data (different layout and added functionality), but now you're giving me ideas for my next project. Nice to encounter another surfer-coder — rare bread.

Comment: Cheers Brad, this was totally what I was looking for!

Comment: Brad, does this method still work for you?  The rmtp streams do not seem to work after a while.  Maybe I'm unclear on how you are using them.